# Same APNs certificates for two different FCM projects with same app id

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have FCM working with my app in production then I requested APNs certificates and uploaded them to development & production section in Firebase as written in the docs and everything is working as expected.

Now, I created another Firebase project which serves as a development environment, with an identical app id, but with different FCM Server key.

If I upload the same certificates I used in production to this development environment, will the FCM notifications be sent to development only or to production as well?

Answer (score 0):

For APNs It does not support one certificate and two firebase projects.

Answer (score 0):

It will be sent to both.  I just learned the hard way.